# Not able to scan bluetooth devices

Tags: android

I am developing an app which scans the bluetooth devices and list them all. My requirement is that I have to scan for devices as soon as application starts..Now my problem is when i run the app for the first time it only turns on the bluetooth but does not scan for devices..
I can see the bluetooth icon on screen but in log cat getState() method of the BluetoothAdapter shows state as STATE_OFF.
Please anyone help me about this issue ??

Here is my code snippet

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
Set<String> BTList;
ArrayAdapter<String> BTAdapter;
private ListView listView;
 private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if (bluetoothAdapter == null)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Devices does not support Bluetooth",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        bluetoothAdapter.enable();

    if(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        if(bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
    }

    bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                 BTAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                 BTAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
    };


    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    BTAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);
    listView.setAdapter(BTAdapter);     
}



@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //if(bluetoothAdapter != null) 
    //  bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

}

Comment: learn some coding first.

Comment: @Ankit yup thats what i am trying..and thats why i have asked this..

Comment: you can not just add everything in onCreate, learn basics first. This problem itself will solved then.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your AndroidManifest.xml file, if you have these below entries

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```